# Right-click-drag not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When I right-click-drag on my MacBook Pro TB 2017, a transparent window opens up and the dragging motion ''draws'' where I dragged. However, the dragging function does not work. If I release the right click, the window disappears. Happens on both my trackpad and with a external USB mouse. How do I fix this, because I need to right-click drag for some applications?

[image]

Comment: If you turn off bluetooth and disconnect all mice and pointing devices, does that affect things?

Comment: No, it tried and it doesnt work.